# I need to set up a separate environment to do demonstrations

Tags: administration, appexchange, isv

I need to set up a separate environment to do demonstrations for our potential customers, as well as training for our new customers. I have been using the development org, however, that is not suitable going forward. Do either of you have any recommendations on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an ISV, you can log in to the Partner Portal and create new demo orgs for training and demonstration purposes. Unlike regular developer orgs, they have significantly more storage space and licenses. You can also create different types of orgs, such as Group Edition, Professional Edition, and Enterprise Edition systems, so that you can closely mimic what a user of the given edition would be able to do with your app in that edition. See [An Introduction to Environments](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Environments) for more information. ISVs get three types of bonus orgs: developer edition (with expanded licenses and storage), enterprise test editions, and professional test editions. These are probably what you should be using going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Typically we use Partial data or Full sandbox for Training/Demo.

Here is the recommendation from Salesforce.

[image]

Check this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000036AisAAE) for Sandbox Management Best Practices